# Put this word problem into math terms: A man goes to a stream....

Tags: divisibility, word-problem

A man goes to a stream with an 18-pint container and a 26-pint container. Using only these two containers:

a) How does he get 2 pints of water into the larger container?

b) What are all the quantities he can have in the larger container?

This has something to do with GCD/LCM, but I can't figure out how to re-formulate this into mathematical terms in order to solve it. Can someone give me a hand?

Comment: You may want to look at this: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2005/readings/ln6.pdf

Comment: Specifically the part about 2. Die Hard

Comment: $3 \cdot 18 - 2 \cdot 26 = 2$.

Comment: Would the answer to part b) be "all common denominators of 18 and 26"? ... or all prime CD's as 1 does not seem to work?

Comment: Not "all common denominators".  You already should see that the larger container can hold zero pints or 26 pints, neither of which is a common denominator of 18 and 26.  It is suggestive that 2 pints (required in part a) is the greatest common denominator.

Comment: I see, makes sense. Thanks for the clarification.